# Get notifications from a closed Tabris-js app

Tags: javascript, tabris-js

How can I get notifications from the Tabrisjs app in its closed state? similar to the notifications received in apps like Whatsapp or Facebook messanger even when the applications are not open.

The notifications can be either time triggered e.g. displaying a notification at 1200 hrs every day or it can be coming from a server. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1106) from the issue tracker:

- [tabris-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-plugin-firebase) Supports Android (update: And iOS)
- [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/eclipsesource/phonegap-plugin-push) (fork) has been modified to work with iOS
- [pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin](https://github.com/spatialdatalogic/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin) (fork) has been modified for basic functionality to work on iOS and Android

If you're looking for Windows support as well, you might [try some other Cordova plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=push).