# Tabris.js system push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, tabris, tabris-js

I can't find a way to send system push notifications using Tabris.js framework(current version is 2.6.1). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420599/get-notifications-from-a-closed-tabris-js-app) there is a way to send push notifications using the official firebase plugin, but is there a way to do it with the basic framework?

If there is no way to do it without external plugins yet - can you suggest go-to plugin for it that will 100% work on both iOS and Android?

By "system push notifications" I mean native notifications that appear in the phone notifications tab even when the app is running in the background. I don't want to send notifications when the app is closed, so diving into firebase plugin will be overkill for me now.

Comment: did you solve the issue? Have you got an example app available on github?

Answer (score 1):

First, apps don't *send* push notifications.  They receive them.  A push notification originates from outside the app and makes its way to the device.  It sounds like you want to initiate a notification from within the app, so a push notification is not what you are looking for.

You'll need a plugin.  If you [search from the available plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/), there are several available, including [`cordova-plugin-local-notifications`](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/)

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the terms correctly, but I want to send notification inside the app to the device notification panel, not the app screen. I know that some games(like 2048 for example) sending system notifications like "Hey, you haven't played the game for a while, come back!" and this is probably delayed by timer thing coming from the app. Or this is called "local notifications" and what the exact difference in terms then?

Comment: It's hard to say what those apps are doing. They may be running a background task, which is not yet possible (see https://tabris.com/tabris-roadmap) or it could be a cloud push.